# I am stuck with train_test_split of sklearn model_selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(image_data, labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 101)
```

showing the error:

> ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the
>   resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned
>   parameters.

Comment: It is telling you that the passed in data seems to be empty. Best to check image_data and labels.

Comment: what are the shapes of `image_data` and `labels`?

Comment: doc says :"Allowed inputs are lists, numpy arrays, scipy-sparse matrices or pandas dataframes."
you should check the type and shape of the inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n_samples=0 means that your dataset is empty. Check the image_data variable

Comment: what does it mean if I have n_samples=1 in the same error